# Curl GET Request does not return form post data

Tags: php, api, curl, post

I have a form on one page let's say 'x.php' and I am sending this form's data to another page  'y.php' in same folder using post method. Now I am getting the data on 'y.php' through $_POST. Now the issue is when I am trying to get this $_POST data from another file let's say 'z.php'in another folder using curl, it's showing an empty array.
Note* - This all is working on localhost.

Here is the Code for 'z.php; from where I am trying to get the data.

```
    $url = 'http://localhost/folder-name/y.php';
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response_json = curl_exec($ch);
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);
    $response=json_decode($response_json, true);
    echo $httpCode. "<br>" ;
    print_r($response);
```

Now I have checked the status & it is '200' so the curl is working fine. But I am not being able to get the POST data that is coming on 'y.php'.

Please forgive if the question is not brief & feel free to ask me about this if you have any query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make an HTTP request to a URL handled by the a PHP program, that program runs and it gets some data about the request.

If you POST some data in that request, then that data will be available via `$_POST` when the program executes.

If you subsequently make another HTTP request, then the data the program will have will be the data in *that* request and not the previous one.

---

> I have a form on one page let's say 'x.php' and I am sending this form's data to another page 'y.php' in same folder using post method.

So first you make a POST request to `y.php` and in `y.php` you have some data in `$_POST`.

> ```
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
> ```

Then you make a GET request to `y.php`. This is a different request. You won't have the data in `$_POST` this time.

---

If you want the data to be available on a subsequent request then you will need to store it somewhere, such as a database, and fetch it from wherever you store it on the subsequent request.

Comment: I tried saving the $_POST data into $_SESSION variable but that didn't work as well. Thanks for answering anyway.

Comment: @nishantsharma — You aren't sending any cookies in your request with cURL so sessions won't work (and that's assuming the POST request was made with cURL in the first place and you aren't trying to access a session associated with a cookie given to the browser and not to your PHP).